# Magento grouped products associated products less than expected

Tags: magento, product, magento-1.8

I am importing a large amount of products into Magento, where there are a lot of grouped products. These grouped products can have more than 100 associated simple products.

The import that I'm running is correct and gives no error. However, when I look in the backend, a lot of products have less associated products than they should have. For example there is a product with normally 104 associated products but has 38 right now. This number stays the same whatever I try.

I have checked the `app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Import/Entity/Product/Type/Grouped.php` file, and did some dumps in there.

The `foreach` on line `104` gives them all correctly. However, from the part on line `153` and on, it becomes 66. After that it aparently lowers again to 38, but I could not find where that gets lowered.

I am currently stuck because I don't know what might cause this. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check that the childs products have information in the relationship attribute ?

Thanks

Comment: The products that are not linked to the grouped product do not have a record in `catalog_product_link`, if that is what you mean. So magento just simple skips the first ones until a certain point.

Answer (score 0):

Something to try,  are you importing grouped and simple products together in one import?   Typically for large associations I have separated these because sometimes the parents have not been fully created first before their associated children during an import.  Imagine the import is going and 50 of the child products are created before the parent, then 38 afterwards.  The association to parent would then only include the 38 children. Are you using data profiles or a custom API?

Comment: We are using the AMartinez_customimportexport module, the CSV is generated in the correct order (first simple products, then grouped). Even if it's an update it doesn't link the already existing products correctly. I might try to do a run with the simple and grouped products separated on monday, but I doubt that will me the solution in this case.

Comment: I have tried this, to no avail. The result is no different than simple and grouped products combined.